# How do I call a function and redirect the webpage to different website (in different tab) in one button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a website, and on that website I have many `imagebutton`.
Each time I click the `imagebutton`, I want to call a function and after that it will be redirected to a different website (on different tab).
Is it possible? How?

Comment: define a click event and you can do all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `OnClick` event of your `ImageButton`:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{ 
    // Call your function and do processing here

    // Open a new page in a new tab
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"OpenWindow","window.open('http://www.AnotherWebsite.com','_newtab');",true);
}
```

This method will open the new tab *after* you call your function, as per your question. It will also allow you to ensure any additional processing has been successfully completed before you open a new tab for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Add a link to your `imagebutton`:

```
<a class="link">YourImageButton</a>
```

And this script too.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $("a.link").on("click",function(){
         window.open('www.targetwebsite.com','_blank');
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank"><img src="imagePath" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "just_a_key", "<script>window.open('www.url.com', '_self')</script>");
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: open in the same window with _self

Comment: OP specifically requested a way to open a new tab, though. Not on the same window.

Comment: Tab is something that opens in a new window